# How to specify RegularlySampledQ TimeSeries with EndOfMonth date unit MinimumTimeIncrement?

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

`"EndOfMonth"` is date unit that can be used with date functions.  When specifying a `TimeSeries` object with date increments you can specify the date unit increment so that you obtain a regularly sampled time series. I need date units of `"EndOfMonth"` in the `TimeSeries`.

If I supply the month end dates the result is an irregularly sampled time series.

```
 TimeSeries[
  Transpose@{DateRange[{2006, 12, 31}, {2007, 9, 30}, "EndOfMonth"], 
    Range[10]}] // RegularlySampledQ
(* False *)
```

If I request a time increment of `"EndOfMonth"` then `TimeSeries` errors.

```
TimeSeries[Range[10], {Automatic, {2007, 9, 30}, {1, "EndOfMonth"}}]
```

> TemporalData::tpspc: The time specification {Automatic,{2007,9,30},{1,EndOfMonth}} should be one of Automatic, a time range, a list containing a list of explicit times, or a list containing one such specification for each path in the data.

If I request a time increment of `"Month"` I get a regularly sampled time series but the dates are not month ends.

```
(m = TimeSeries[
    Range[10], {Automatic, {2007, 9, 30}, {1, "Month"}}]) // RegularlySampledQ

(* True *)

(m["Dates"] /. DateObject[d_, ___] :> DateObject[d]) === 
 DateRange[DateObject@{2006, 12, 31}, DateObject@{2007, 9, 30}, "EndOfMonth"]

(* False *)
```

How can a regularly sampled `TimeSeries` of date unit `"EndOfMonth"` be created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the purpose of the `TemporalRegularity` option.

> TemporalRegularity  is an option for TemporalData, TimeSeries, and
>   EventSeries that controls whether the paths are assumed to be
>   uniformly spaced in time.

When setting this option, the dates themselves are ignored and a standard index `{0,1,...,n}` is used in its place, allowing for non-uniform dates/times to be used for labeling and plotting purposes while leveraging algorithms that require uniform spacing.

```
TimeSeries[
  Transpose@{DateRange[{2006, 12, 31}, {2007, 9, 30}, "EndOfMonth"], 
    Range[10]}, TemporalRegularity -> True] // RegularlySampledQ

(* True *)
```

**Edit**

It is interesting to look at the `InputForm` of the `TimeSeries` object that is produced by setting `TemporalRegularity` to `True`. Note the use of a uniform time specification.

```
TemporalData[TimeSeries, {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, 
  {TemporalData`UniformTimeSpecification[{3376512000, 3379190400, 3381609600, 
    3384288000, 3386880000, 3389558400, 3392150400, 3394828800, 3397507200, 
    3400099200}]}, 1, {"Continuous", 1}, {"Discrete", 1}, 1, 
  {ValueDimensions -> 1, DateFunction -> Automatic, 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}, 
   TemporalRegularity -> True}}, True, 10.1]
```

Obviously this is exposing internal functionality that is subject to change.

Comment: The solution was staring at me the whole time. LOL!  (+1) I don't think there will be a better answer but we'll let it sit nonetheless.

Comment: @Edmund happens to me all the time :)

Comment: @AndyRoss, given an aribtrary `DateObject` with month and possibly date specified, how to return `EndOfMonth`